# Added SSL to Static IP Address API Server

Tags: php, api, ssl

I am not sure if anyone have this issue.

I have an

- Local API Server + Database with Static IP
- Web Site

My API server is holding all the information and the Web site is just a middleman and point all transaction to the server. So if we are talking about MVC, the website is like the View, and my API is the Model and Controller.

So my question is how should I add SSL to the API Server? Because my API server is running on an IP, so SSL is unable to attached to a Public IP. (Quoted from GoDaddy. IP Address to SSL will stop on 1st October 2016).

I seen online, saying to direct a domain name to the IP Address and get SSL for the domain but my question is, is there any security risk because technically I still access through the public IP directly.

Please advise on how should I proceed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you give it a hostname and a SSL cert for that hostname, anyone accessing via IP will get an "invalid SSL hostname mismatch" type error (exact error depends on what browser/client/etc. is being used to access it).  This is because your 10.42.56.113 doesn't match "db.example.com" and the SSL cert is for "db.example.com".

If you are using code to make the connection, then you need to know that some implementations of some things allow you to set flags/arguments/whatever that say "yes, use a self signed cert" or "don't freak out over SSL errors connect anyway".

But, that is bad practice.  Do it right.  Get a hostname assigned to your IP, get a SSL certificate for it (let's encrypt makes it super easy), and connect to it via that host name.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: So I can conclude that 

1. Get a domain for my API Server

Comment: The "Enter"...

1. Get a domain for my API Server
2. Point it to my public IP
3. Get a SSL Cert for that domain and install it on my server

Comment: Yes.  Plenty of low cost/free domains available, let's encrypt makes using SSL easy.  StartSSL also offers a free basic certificate, but they don't work on subdomains.